# Web hosting at home on Apache 2, after port forward nothing shows up when I go to my external IP

Tags: networking, ubuntu, apache-http-server

Ubuntu server is all set up on my HP Server and I port forward through my router and my modem and when someone types my external IP they cant get in it. It just times out.

Comment: the tester is accessing the site from outside your network right? it will be necessary unless you have a high end router and hair-pinning enabled.  if they are, start by going to http://canyouseeme.org and checking to see if the port reports as open. if not, first confirm that the service is listening on the right interface (not 127.0.0.1), that the port is allowed on teh server firewall, router firewall, that your NAT rules are correct on both the router and modem. remember the Three P's: a Process listening on a known Port, with a Pathway from the remote client.

Answer (score 0):

Many ISPs block port 80 and other common server ports.  If so, traffic may not even reach your server.  Try using a non-standard port, perhaps above 1024.

Try having your friend use a tool than can traceroute TCP connections.  This may help determine where the connection is being blocked.   Combining their results with a traceroute from your server to their external IP may provide more insight.